# Chromiumのビルド時にフォルダ配下の容量が非常に大きくなる

Tags: python, c++, c, google-chrome

下記手順に従って、Windows環境でChromiumのリリースビルドを行ったところ、ファイル容量が48GBでした。
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

しかし、Chromeのインストーラーを使ってインストールされたファイルは700MB程度です。
ブラウジングに最低限必要なファイルを出力するためのビルドオプションはありますか？

現在使用しているビルドオプションは下記となります。

```
gen gen out/Default --args="is_debug=false enable_nacl=false symbol_level=0 blink_symbol_level=0 is_component_build=true"
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

Comment: ビルド時のオプションやパラメータ等の情報も示した方が、具体的なアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

48GBというのは`out/Default/`の全ファイルの容量だと思いますが、全ファイルが実行時に必要というわけではありません。2度とビルドしないなら、実行時に必要なファイル以外は消してしまって構わないでしょう。実行時に必要なファイルは、Chrome のインストーラでインストールされたファイルを見れば判断できます。

Comment: 普通は削除しないと思います。実行に必要なファイルだけ配布したいという目的なら、インストーラをビルドしてインストーラを配布します。